# Internationaliz the passed variable from the class to the .jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to internationalize the headerMessage which is passed from the `StudentAdmissionController` to the `AdmissionForm.jsp` after accessing the  `studentmessages_de.properties` and `studentmessages_en.properties` depends on the browser language but I do not have any idea how can I manage it for the passed headerMessage?

I appretiate any help.

**StudentAdmissionController**

```
package com.stack;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentAdmissionController {

    @InitBinder
    public void iniBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
        //binder.setDisallowedFields(new String[] {"studentMobile"});
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "studentDOB", new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
        //add to handle a specific data. 
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class,"studentName", new StudentNameEditor());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admissionForm.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAdmissionForm() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");
        return model;
    }

    // Aded
    // This method is being called by every request.
    @ModelAttribute
    public void addingCommonObjects(Model model1) {
        model1.addAttribute("headerMessage", "University of Berlin, Germany ");

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/submitAdmissionForm.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student1") Student student1, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");
            return model;

        }

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionSuccess");
        return model;
    }
}
```

**AdmissionForm.jsp**

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<body>
    <h1>${headerMessage}</h1>

    <h1> <spring:message code="label.admissionForm" /></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**studentmessages_en.properties**

```
label.admissionForm = STUDENT ADMISSION FROM ENGINEERING COURSES
label.headerMessage = University of Berlin, Germany
```

**studentmessages_de.properties**

```
label.admissionForm = STUDENTEN ZULASSUNG FÜR ENGINEERING Lehrveranstaltungen
label.headerMessage = Universität zu Berlin, Deutschland
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html), you can load locale-specific resource bundle that is appropriate for the current user's locale.

1.Load ResourceBundle according to locale at servlet:

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("studentmessages_en");
ServletContext ctx = request.getSession().getServletContext();
ctx.setAttribute("resourceBundle", messages);
```

2.Fetch at JSP

```
<%  ServletContext ctx=this.getServletContext();
    ResourceBundle res=(ResourceBundle)ctx.getAttribute("resourceBundle"); %>

<%=res.getString("label.headerMessage") %>
```

Comment: Please can u adapt ur code to my code since I am getting `The method getServletContext() is undefined for the type StudentAdmissionController` when I place it inside the `addingCommonObjects()` in the `StudentAdmissionController` class. Why do u have added just the `studentmessages_en` to the bundle and what a bout `studentmessages_de`?

Comment: At the Moment I am getting `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSession() from the type Request`?